# DataNitro - get selected Cell / Range

Tags: python, excel, vba, datanitro

I am writing an Excel Macro that parses a user's selection and uses the data to create a SQL database table. I'm using DataNitro to fire off the scripts straight from Excel, but need help feeding the Excel selected values into my python script.

I know that DataNitro lets you access and edit Cells straight from Python, but all the examples they provide are hard-coded ( eg `CellRange("A1:B5")` ). Is there a way to get a selected range, similar to VBA's `Selection.Address` method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `active_cell` command to get the selected cell: https://datanitro.com/docs/cell.html?highlight=active_cell#active_cell

There's currently no way to get a selected range, but we do plan to add it in the future. 
[Source: I'm one of the developers.]